# ADO.NET database saves, but doesn't save

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I have a program that allows the user to fill out their information, it is then stored in a local database. I can execute the stored procedure that handles it just fine, however when I check the data through visual studio the changes aren't there. However if I run my program and enter a duplicate primary key, the error is thrown that the value already exists. I've made sure that there are no duplicate files.

Any suggestions?

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewUser]
@username as text,
@password as text,
@attackMethod as text,
@statPreference as text
AS
    INSERT INTO Users
    VALUES (@username,@password,@attackMethod,@statPreference)
RETURN 0
```

and the code that runs to throw it into the database.

```
            try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("NewUser",connection);
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attackMethod", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatPreference", SqlDbType.Text);
            command.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.Name;
            command.Parameters["@Password"].Value = this.Password;
            command.Parameters["@attackMethod"].Value = this.AttackMethod;
            command.Parameters["@StatPreference"].Value = this.SkillPreference;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            connection.Close();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: are you sure the database you're checking in visual studio is the same database your ADO object is saving too?

Comment: `int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();` You can have a look at how many rows changed

Comment: Kritner- I believe so, I've cleaned up all files and folders, removed the connection and reconnected it to the db.

sky- Thank you I hadn't noticed that it returns an int for rows affected. As expected it hands back a 1 unless I cause an error.

Comment: How are you checking the data through VS? It looks like that's the only "problem".

Comment: SteveCav- I've been opening my database through visual studio using the solution explorer, or just opening it under server explorer. Once I can see the table, I just right click and hit show table data.

Answer (score 0):

`AddWithValue` method is supposed to take a parameterName and an object representing the value, not the `SqlDbType` so there is a problem there.  Also @Username is not the same as @username.  One has a capital U.

Try this pattern instead:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@username ", SqlDbType.Text);
command.Parameters["@username "].Value = this.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've changed my code but still have the same problem. I'm a little bewildered the compiler didn't have a fit over the way I had been doing it.

Comment: 2nd parameter in the AddWithValue method is of type object.  That is why no compiler error/warning

Comment: Hi @ArgentDrake text maps to SqlDbType.VarChar so there may be an issue there as well.  A better mapping would be nvarchar -> SqlDbType.NVarChar

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It turns out visual studio was generating a copy of my database into the debug folder. It explains why it would save but not be shown. To fix this, I just removed my data connection and pointed a new one at the .mdf file in my debug directory.

Thank you all for the help!